# Missing options in settings for language French

Tags: android, localization

To Reproduce:
On a device with Android 13:
Go to settings -> System  -> Languages & Input -> Languages

And then select French.
You will see that there are no options under French for Algiers or Benenois.

On a device with Android 8.0:
Doing something similar above leads to variants for the French.

I expected an android 13 device to have the option to select a variant of the French language, why is it missing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.